# Ignite ui combobox with mvc 4.0 helpers load from database error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, ignite-ui

i am trying to use a ignite ui componet called combobox , and i was trying to follow this tutorial on the igniteui page.

heres is the link:
http://www.igniteui.com/combo/aspnet-mvc-helper

the tutorial uses a repository factory, and i am using entity framework model with linq.
i already use some of the components of ignite ui, like igGrid, and i followed the tutorial on this video

http://www.infragistics.com/products/jquery/grid/videos/iggrid-entity-framework-model 
to make the grid bind with ef model.

I am having problems with the binding of the data to the combobox,i wqas trying to follow the same approach to the bing of iggrid, but i am having some problems..

in my view i have got this..

```
 @(Html.Infragistics().ComboFor(item=>item.IDCliente)

                .Width("270px")
                .DataSourceUrl(Url.Action("cliente-combo-data"))
                .ValueKey("ID")
                .TextKey("Name")
                .DataBind()
                .Render()
            )
```

in the controller i have this:

```
    [ComboDataSourceAction]
    [ActionName("cliente-combo-data")]
    public ActionResult ComboData()
    {
        return View(LicenciamentoMVC.Models.ClienteModel.GetListaClientes());
    }
```

and in my cliente class i have this:

```
 public class ClienteModel
{
    private static Cliente entity;
    public static IQueryable<Cliente> GetListaClientes()
    {
        MvcApplication1Context db = new MvcApplication1Context();

        var customers = from c in db.Clientes
                        orderby c.IDCliente descending
                        where c.Rem==0
                        select c;

        return customers.AsQueryable<Cliente>();
    }
```

the **error** that is giving me is:
'**System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'IDCliente' and no extension method 'IDCliente' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

What changes do i need to do, or the best way to go is instead of using entity model go for repository...
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

the solution was to change the way i initialize the combobox in  the view, i was following igniteui tutorial, and the example that they have put on the combo was a bit complicated for a example/tutorial on how to use the combobox....
here is the code for mvc with helpers

```
@(Html.Infragistics().Combo().
              ID("comboClientes").
              TextKey("Nome").
              AutoComplete(false).
              FilteringType(ComboFilteringType.Local).
              RenderMatchItemsCondition(ComboRenderMatchItemsCondition.StartsWith).
              ValueKey("IDCliente").DataSourceUrl(Url.Action("clientes-combo")).
              DataBind().
              Render())
```

thanks